# How to calibrate ACS712 current sensor for a 3v3 MCU (Adafruit Feather M0 with LoRa module)?

Tags: calibration

This is my first question in Stack Exchange. I'm completely new to Electronics, but I hope my question is meaningful.

I'm in the process of measuring voltages and currents in my off-grid solar PV setup. We'd want to monitor the PV system remotely, so we're developing a LoRaWAN based IOT setup. We've chosen Adafruit Feather M0 with LoRa module because it has got LoRa module, and it is programmable in Arduino IDE.

I was able to design the simple circuit - voltage divider for Voltage, and ACS712 for Current. I'm facing problems in calibrating the ACS712 sensor with Adafruit feather M0, which is basically a 3v3 logic based MCU.

The specific problem I'm facing is that the 3v3 MCU makes the calibration logic a challenging one. All the articles and YouTube videos I've seen (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lisprJs5sNU&t=320s and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LGM8v1b41So) are concerned with using ACS 712 sensor interfaced with 5v logic based microcontrollers. I'm wondering if I just have to replace 5v with 3v3 or I've to make any other calculations, to make it relevant for 3v3 MCU. I mean to say, incase of 5v MCU, 0 to 1023 is equivalent to 0 to 5v. Will the logic be the same in case of 3v3 MCU, i.e., whether 0 to 1023 is equivalent to 0 to 3v3 in a 3v3 MCU?

Any response is highly appreciated. If any of you have used ACS712 current sensor with Adafruit M0 LoRa boards or any 3v3 MCUs, please share from your experience. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Build the voltage divider as explained below.  As your initial test, see what ADC reading you get with zero current.  Then rig up some way to make test currents from an isolated supply, and connect it in both polarities taking some data, eg +1A gives you this, -1A gives you that.   You might also consider an INA219 solution for both voltage and current.

Comment: In general, ADCs return a number (0..1023 for 10 bits) which is the ratio of the input signal voltage in respect to reference voltage Vref, which often equals Vdd, but often can be different. Other than that, follow @ChrisStratton above: take some measurement to learn the 512 means 1A or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

The ACS712 is obsolete.
The eg ACS723 is a more recent replacement.

[ACS712 datasheet here](https://www.allegromicro.com/~/media/Files/Datasheets/ACS712-Datasheet.ashx)

Reading the datasheet rather than watching You Tube videos will usually tell you much.
The device is ONLY 5V supply specified.

Fig 4A page 6 (count down 1 2 3 4 ...) shows that Vout is centred on VCC/2.
Vout = Vcc/2 +/- k mV/A with k varying with current rating of the part used (which we do not know).
Vout_max is shown as about 3.5V.
IF you operated the device on 5V you could resistively divide the output slightly to limit Vout_max to 3V3 or less.

The ACS723 [datasheet here](https://www.allegromicro.com/~/media/Files/Datasheets/ACS723-Datasheet.ashx) is also a 5V only part with similar output characteristics - but perhaps ~= 4.5V max Vout so a slightly greater Vout divider needed.

Options:

- Use one of these device with 5V supply and an output voltage divider.

or

- Use a 3V3 rated part.

---

---

Notes:

The ACS712 is obsolete. It can be used but is not recommended. For one off tasks it is fine.

You can use different voltage MCU and sensor if desired, as long as the interface signals are within spec.

- If you are happy to provide 5V and 3V3 supplies then that's fine.
- **IF** you can use the same supply for both, so much the better.

The ADC range of the MCU depends on the device

- it may be 0 to < Vdd, or
- 0-Vdd or
- 0 - > Vdd (this is much less common, but in some cases is allowed).

The ACS712 with Vdd=5V has Vout within 0-3V3.

The ACS723 with Vdd=5V has max Vout > 3V3.

- **IF** the MCU cannot handle analog Vin > 3V3 then you will need to reduce the analog voltage.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused now. May I know the relation between supply voltage of sensor, and the operating voltage (equivalent analog reference) of MCU! Do you mean to say that I can only use a sensor whose supply voltage must equal to the processor operating voltage?

Comment: ACS712 is analog IC. It is calibrated in factory. You need to calibrate your ADC.

Comment: +1 for "rather than watching You Tube".

Answer (score 0):

You must separate things. One thing is the analog input of your MCU: what is its range? Often the range is 0-Vdd but often you have a Vref pin where to apply a reference, and the ADC will measure from 0 to Vref. Often Vref is simply tied to Vdd but if you want more precision you can also put for example a 0.1V on Vref, and the ADC will measure voltages from 0 to 0.1V.

Then, you have an analog output ranging from 0 to, say, Voutmax. Is that voltage (Voutmax) compatible with your analog input? If the output is (or can sometimes be) too large (high), you can use a voltage divider on it, as already suggested. If it is too little, you can work on Vref on the analog input to improve precision.

Finally, the power supply of the various chips. They are *power supplies*, and have nothing to do with the signals you operate on. It is fine to have a sensor powered with 24 volts and an MCU powered with 2.7 volts. But, when the two get connected together, the wire (signal) connecting both must be correct: tolerable and meaningful for both. If a sensor, no matter its power supply, outputs a +/-10V signal, you can't connect that signal directly to your MCU. If instead a sensor, no matter its power supply, emits a signal from 0 to 3.3V, then you can connect that signal to your MCU (3.3V), or to an MCU powered at 5V (losing some precision if Vref = Vdd).

Of course, generating two different DC power supplies is not good per se: if it is avoidable, avoid it, as pointed out by the other answer.